# Blender: multiple actions - objects move when I add a new one

Tags: blender

I am a beginner with Blender and I searched about working with actions but have not found the solution to my problem.
I work with a file containing many actions where each action represents a specific body movement, using an armature. Here is my workflow:

1. Create new action.
2. Create fake user.
3. Move the armature and save a few keyframes "LocRot".
4. Push down action.
5. Repeat with next action.

Then I have a script that renders all the actions in one go.

The problem: sometimes after adding a new action or a new object, other actions are affected and move to another location. What could cause that?

Also: Is it possible to make some objects (other than the main object's armature) appear on only specific actions? And either make them disappear or go out of the camera view for the other actions.